# I save image in storage/app/public why when I run website on server image not show

Tags: laravel, vue.js, server, storage, local

I save image in storage/app/public 
when I run the website on localhost, I can see my image
but when I run the website in server image not show. It says '404 (Not Found)'

Um... When I run my website on localhost image will save to public/storage but in server I have only public_html and image don't save on public_html/storage

I use laravel for backend
and vue for frontend

I try to connect SSH access
[image]

Comment: Did you update the symlink on server?

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: you will need to browse to the directory where you installed laravel. and then run that command

Comment: It says  symlink(): No such file or directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following command on your server:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

This command will create a symlink of your storage in public folder. As laravel app's only public folder is publicly accessible, so it can read data from public/storage

Comment: Please see what I try in edit (picture) and give me some advice

Comment: where is your laravel app directory ? cd inside the directory and run the command there

Comment: Now I already make a symlink but It make in public/storage and now I use public_html is base on the server . How should I do?

Comment: yes, It appears green text tell me success on public/storage

Comment: now all your saved image should be in your public/storage folder and can be accessible by the app, please check

Comment: I don't know why.. You can check the picture this https://uppic.cc/d/5D97  , https://uppic.cc/d/5D98

Comment: Oh I check it and notice error syntax. Now it's OK thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

Run , php artisan storage:link command in your server.

it will create a symbolic link of storage in your public folder.

Comment: Sorry, I really don't know how to run commands in server. Tell me please. I use Filezilla

Comment: Please see what I try in edit (picture) and give me some advice